# Rendering a UI using IValueConverter using just c# code

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, binding

I am c# and **silverlight-5** beginner.

First i had to create object by deserializing an xml string. I have done that succesfully  but now my next step is to create GUI using the object elements. I have idea that i have to use "`IValueConverter`" for doing this. But how that i dont know.

My Program class which contains the object is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections;
namespace Model.XML
{
    public class ProgramControl
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string xmlstring = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
                       <parameter>  
                       <name>max_amount</name>
                       <label>Max Amount</label>
                       <unit>Millions</unit>
                       <component>
                       <type>Combo</type>
                       <attributes>
                       <type>Integer</type>
                       <displayed>4</displayed>
                       <selected>0</selected>
                       <items>
                       <item>5</item>
                       <item>10</item>
                       <item>20</item>
                       <item>50</item>
                       </items>
                       </attributes>
                       </component >
                       </parameter>";    

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameter));
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));

            Parameter parameter = (Parameter)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);


            foreach (var item in parameter.Component.Attributes.Items)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }    

            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Component.Type);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Label);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Unit);

        } 
    }
}
```

**Now the question is how can i create GUI from the object obtained on deserializing (IValueConverter )?**

EDIT:
I have little idea of how it can be achieved:

First thing is in the class containing "IValueConverter" interface we have to convert(using Convert() function) the objects(obtained on deserializing) in to parameters and then pass those parameteres (containing combo box created in c# here) through `return` to the xaml codewhich contains the container to render the GUI we just created using c#.

And in Xaml code we just need to create container which will display the combo box and other labels and text we created in c# code in previous step. (We don't have to create combo box using xaml here, it is created in c# code inside the class containing IValueConverter interface which returns the UI).

For example: (It's rough idea to make you understand properly, there may be some syntatical error):

My "MyValueConverter.cs" class is suppose:

```
public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {

        List<parameter> list = value as List<Parameter>;
        List<UIElement> result = new List<UIElement>();

        foreach(parameter p in list)
        {
            UIElement newEle = null;
            if (p.component.type == "Combo")
            {
                newEle = new ComboBox();

            }
            result.add(newEle);
        }
        return result;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////// and so on ://///////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

Whereas in xaml file i have to create a container that will render the UI created in c#(IValueConverter interface class). **So we have to chose any container which must be capable of rendering the combo box , label, text all the datas shown in  GUI of snapshot (conatiner could be StackPanel because there are more than one thing to be displayed)**.

my  xaml code will be just containign a container like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RenderingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:RenderingTest.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <this:MyValueConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <!-- There should be container here to render the combo box
             created using c# code in "MyValueConverter" class -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any help in  achieveing it please ? Please do not hesitate to ask if couldn't understand yet.

Comment: Have a look at Implicit Data Templates.

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt Could you please explain in a bit more detail. And do you know how to achieve it using IValueConverter interface (converter())?

Comment: IValueConverter converts data to another format ready to be displayed by UI controls, not to provide the UI it self.

Comment: @har07 But i have element values like "Type","Name","Label","Unit" etc. in c# code these value are supposed to be give a GUI, Like "Type" here is combo box. so it must give a Combo Box GUI with item "5,10,20,50". and "label" as "Max Amount". This kind of GUI (see snap shot) i have to achieve. could you please give me sample to get idea would be a big help. Thaznks

Comment: @user234839 Please read the introductory MSDN articles about [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx) and [Data Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903947(v=vs.95).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could use Implicit Data Types for this.

In your xaml you define a template for a certain datatype:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="ComboParameter">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Path=label}" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=items}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=unit}"/>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

You better create different types depending on the type-element value. Another solution is to create a large template for the type Parameter, and show the appropriate elements depending on what the Parameter-type contains. But I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Then you can use an ItemsControl to display all parameters:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parameters}" />
```

The different parameters will be rendered in different ways depending on what type it has.

Comment: thanks and how my other classes look like. I mean class containing " IValueConverter" interface ? and other classes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but my solution is to replace use of IValueConverter.

Comment: But what is the diffezrence between the way you do and IValuConverter interface (with Convert and ConvertBack() functions) ?

Comment: I am impementing your way and will come soon to mark it solved as it works

Comment: And how to handle your xaml code in c# code behind.

Comment: IValueConverter are more suitable for values. A good example is if you have a boolean property on an object, and this boolean control if a part of the object should be visible or not. Then you can have a converter that converts from bool to Visibility. In your case you want to display objects, and in this case it is better to use implicit data templates. This way an object will be displayed according to the rules you have set up in the template, and you don't even have to explicitly mark the code with what template should be used. The datatype controls what template should be used.

Comment: You don't need to handle the xaml code in the code behind, just set the DataContext of your control from the code behind, the rest will be handled with bindings in the xaml.

Comment: Thnaks for trying to help me but you are still not able to understand what i want to do. Please see the edited question. I have to achieve it using "IValueConverter" interface only. And how? i have given idea

Comment: @user234839: Håkan's solution is the correct way to solve this. Why do you "have to achieve it using "IValueConverter" interface only"?

Comment: @Martin Because i dont have to display ComboBox , textblocks etc. using xaml. Actually i have obtained Objects on deserializing the xml. Now i have objects that contains comboBox and all. And i can only render them on a container(thic container could be stackpanel/canvas etc.).So i just need a container in xaml where IValueConverter will be used to convert the objects obtained on dersializing into parameters(which are then returned thgrough Converter() of IvalueConverter interface). Have you understood ? please let me know i am stuck here since a week. Thats why i am not able to use his code.

Comment: because i dont need to create combo box manually using xaml. i have to create them using c# (it will be dynamic) when i found "Combo" in <type> of my xml(please see my xml code in snapshot)

Comment: @Martin Please let me know if you dont understand what i am trying to achieve and how ? I request you to please help me.