# How to create XAML container for combo box which is created?

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I am working on c# **silverlight5** and i am using mvvm approach to do so. I have a situation where i have to create **container** in xaml which could accomodate the  GUI which contains combo box and labels and text boxes which are created using c# code.

I then i have to bind this container created in xaml to use it in c#.

This container could be something like stackpanel on which i can have combobox and textbox and label which are created in c#.

Conclusion:

(1)Xaml file will consist of container and binding .
(2) c# code will contain the code for combo box and text box and label and binds the this on container created in xaml.

Could some one please give me a small sample doing this.
would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UserControl` because it's very easy to access UI elements from the code-behind. Example: we want to create a `UserControl` named `DynamicContent`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DynamicContent">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class DynamicContent : UserControl
{
    public DynamicContent(){InitializeComponent();}

    public void AddComboBox(ComboBox combobox)
    {
        LayoutRoot.Childre.Add(combobox);
    }
}
```

But to be honest: I'm not convinced you really need to create controls programmatically, most of the time you can solve a situation like this (when you need to create UI elements dynamically) by using `DataTemplates`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but question is really complex. Your logic i already know but if you really wanna know the situation please go on this link (this question is stil un answered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488983/rendering-a-ui-using-ivalueconverter-using-just-c-sharp-code