# Xaml code explanation

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, canvas, grid

I am working on c# xaml using silverlight and i am bit confused about the hierarchy of this xaml code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <this:MyValueConverter x:Key="TabConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabList, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas></Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="150" Background="red" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="{Binding TabList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}"  Canvas.Top="100" />          
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

When i run it gives a big green  color window(sorry if technical names are not correct), whereas it should also show red color somewhere in same window as it has `Border Width="150" Background="red"` .Could some one please explain me what this code is doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemsControl really just binds to a list and applies a datatemplate (border with background red) for each item in the list.  As for the reason you're only seeing green, well there's probably nothing in the TabList property on your viewmodel.  That way, nothing in the items template renders, and all you see is green.

You'll need to make sure that TabList is bound correctly (it exists on your datacontext, whether that's a view model or not) and that it has items in it.

Here's a simpler version of what you may want to accomplish:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabList, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="150" Background="red" Height="100" />          
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I need your help. Actually i have situation where i created objects from xml using deserialize and those object now supposed to be render GUI (which contains ComboBox, textBox and TextBlock) in a container created using xaml. Could you please help me in creating a container in xaml which accomodate the rendering of ComboBox,TextBlock etc which are created using objects obtained on deserializing. I will use those IValuConverter to convert those objects into parameters. I just need a container from you which must be able to accomodate rendering of UI elements created in c# (with binding)

Comment: Seeing how that deviates from your original question, and I'm not sure of the answer, I would suggest creating a new question.

Comment: Please see the original Question which is not yet been answer and made me not progress since last week. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488983/rendering-a-ui-using-ivalueconverter-using-just-c-sharp-code#23488983

Comment: i guess its a binding problem. How i have to bind it in ViewModel.cs.could you please givea sample.

Comment: You'll basically set your view's datacontext property to your view model.  So this.DataContext = new TabViewModel();

Comment: TabViewModel is not a class. I am not able to uunderstand what are you doing. and how to set dataContext proprty in view model. I just do this there: private ObservableCollection<Parameter> tabList;
        public ObservableCollection<Parameter> TabList
        {
            get { return tabList; }
            set
            {
                tabList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TabList");
            }
        }

Comment: I have " this.DataContext = viewModel.getInstance();" in MainPage classand ViewModel class is executed i am sure of that , i saw on debugging

Comment: Alright, that looks good.  So assuming there are items in the TabList property ... the only issue I could see left is the Canvas.Left property on the Border.  Do you know what the TabConverter does in that case?

Comment: No. Could you explain it please ?

Comment: I can't ... it's not my code.  I'll update my answer with a much simpler version of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks ..Can this TabList accomodate more then one UI elements like combobox and also text box ?

Comment: I think you're getting a little confused, but you'll find that you can put any of those controls in the StackPanel solution I provided.