# How to color a particular row of a grid in c# using silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, grid, silverlight-5.0

I am working on c# silverlight. I have to color(Green) the particular column which is created using c#.

I have grid with 6 rows and 3 columns like this:

```
 Grid myGrid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Width = 350;
            myGrid.Height = 280;
            myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            myGrid.ShowGridLines = false;
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);
            RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef4 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef5 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowDef6 = new RowDefinition();

            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef4);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef5);
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef6);
```

**Now if i have to color second full row(i mean in 3 columns in this row as well) of this grid then  how i will do this ?**

Comment: To my knowledge the `Grid` panel does not support coloring specific rows/columns.  You'll have to try another approach.

Comment: Could just plop a Rectangle or Border with a colored Fill/Background in at the same Row level with the proper columnspan and fake it....but why you'd want to to draw a grid in code instead of xaml would be what I would ask.

Comment: @McGarnagle What do you suggest me  ? I mean i will have 1 combo Box one text box and ont textblock in one row and i want to change color of each row.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes its Ok for me to have border or rectangle with color using c# only but how to do that ?

Comment: @user234839: I see your questions popping up alot, showing no research effort and what is worse: several times now someone hinted you towards a `xaml` solution, using `DataTemplates` instead of code but you refuse to give it a second thought. This whole approach reeks of "only knows a hammer". Håkan Fahlstedt gave you [an excelent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488983/rendering-a-ui-using-ivalueconverter-using-just-c-sharp-code) to one of those questions and I strongly recommend you read and understand how to use `DataTemplates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var greenBackgroundBorder = new Border(){
    Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)};
myGrid.Children.Add(greenBackgroundBorder);

// stay always behind other elements
Canvas.SetZOder(greenBackgroundBorder, -100);

//entire second row
Grid.SetColumnSpan(greenBackgroundBorder,3);
Grid.SetRow(greenBackgroundBorder, 1 );
```

Comment: than ks for the answer but i couldnt understand "Canvas.SetZOder(greenBackgroundBorder, -100);" ?  and "SetZOder" gives error:'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas' does not contain a definition for 'SetZOder'

Comment: @user234839: sorry, just noticed it contains a typo.

Comment: And is it possible to add text in this border ?

Comment: @user234839: add a TextBlock to the same cell

Comment: @Martin I don't think Canvas.ZOrder has any effect in a Grid, does it?

Comment: No.. Actuyally i just print

Comment: No actually i just rendered text block on vorder and it worked. and i didnt used canvas.

Comment: @user234839: Yes, it has an effect. It is somewhat counterintuitive that an `AttachedProperty` from the `Canvas` class has an effect outside the class, but you can use `ZOrder` inside all `Panels` from the Silverlight Base Library.